# App Crashing when inflating Listview with Custom Adapter with measureHeightOfChildren()

Tags: android, listview

My App crashes when I inflate my listview with this costum layout I have tried everything from the different answers but cannt find the right answer... The first if is to only inflate a view with a checkbox to certain views.... Please help

```
    package com.codiaq.launcher.alpha.Preferences;



public class SettingsAppearanceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FunctionsAp>{



Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
FunctionsAp data[] = null;
Class c;
SettingsHandler sh;

public SettingsAppearanceAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, FunctionsAp[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    sh = new SettingsHandler(context);
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if(data[position].title.equals(context.getString(R.string.fullscreen))
    || data[position].title.equals(context.getString(R.string.black_statnav))
    || data[position].title.equals(context.getString(R.string.tint_background))){
        HolderCheckbox holder = null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_with_checkbox, parent, false);

            holder = new HolderCheckbox();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            if(position == 0){
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(sh.getFullscreen());
            }
            if(position == 1){
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(sh.getBlackStatNav());
                }
            if(position == 2){
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(sh.getTintBackground());
            }
            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean checked) 
                {
                    // Cast it so we can access the public functions
                       SettingsActivityAppearance.checkboxSelected(checked, position);
                }
            });

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (HolderCheckbox) row.getTag();
        }

        FunctionsAp weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
        holder.txtDesc.setText(weather.description);
        //holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

        return row;
    }
    else{
        WeatherHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new WeatherHolder();
       // holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    FunctionsAp weather = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
    holder.txtDesc.setText(weather.description);
    //holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

    return row;
    }
}

static class WeatherHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
}
static class HolderCheckbox{
    TextView txtDesc;
    TextView txtTitle;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

Comment: Every time you have an exception try to post the stacktrace!:)

Comment: You'll find the reason of the crash in your logcat